# Change data in an immutable way with Java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider this code:

```
Function<BigDecimal,BigDecimal> func1 = x -> x;//This could be anything
Function<BigDecimal,BigDecimal> func2 = y -> y;//This could be anything
Map<Integer,BigDecimal> data = new HashMap<>();

Map<Integer,BigDecimal> newData = 
    data.entrySet().stream().
        collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,i -> 
            func1.apply(i.getValue())));

List<BigDecimal> list = 
    newData.entrySet().stream().map(i -> 
        func2.apply(i.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically what I'm doing is updating an HashMap with func1,to apply a second trasformation with func2 and to save second time updated value in a list.
I DID all in immutable way generating the new objects newData and list.

MY QUESTION:
It is possible to do that streaming the original HashMap (data) once?

I tried this:

```
Function<BigDecimal,BigDecimal> func1 = x -> x;
Function<BigDecimal,BigDecimal> func2 = y -> y;
Map<Integer,BigDecimal> data = new HashMap<>();
List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<>();

Map<Integer,BigDecimal> newData = 
    data.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Entry::getKey,i -> 
        {
            BigDecimal newValue = func1.apply(i.getValue());
            //SIDE EFFECT!!!!!!!
            list.add(func2.apply(newValue));
            return newValue;
    }));
```

but doing so I have a side effect in list updating so I lost the 'immutable way' requirement.

Comment: So you need to get two object out of one stream one list and one map correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like an ideal use case for the upcoming `Collectors.teeing` method in JDK 12. Here's the [webrev](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~tvaleev/webrev/8205461/r6/) and here's the [CSR](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209685). You can use it as follows:

```
Map.Entry<Map<Integer, BigDecimal>, List<BigDecimal>> result = data.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
             Collectors.toMap(
                     Map.Entry::getKey, 
                     i -> func1.apply(i.getValue())),
             Collectors.mapping(
                     i -> func1.andThen(func2).apply(i.getValue()),
                     Collectors.toList()),
             Map::entry));
```

`Collectors.teeing` collects to two different collectors and then merges both partial results into the final result. For this final step I'm using JDK 9's [`Map.entry(K k, V v)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) static method, but I could have used any other container, i.e. `Pair` or `Tuple2`, etc.

For the first collector I'm using your exact code to collect to a `Map`, while for the second collector I'm using [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) along with [`Collectors.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--), using [`Function.andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) to compose your `func1` and `func2` functions for the mapping step.

---

**EDIT:** If you cannot wait until JDK 12 is released, you could use this code meanwhile:

```
public static <T, A1, A2, R1, R2, R> Collector<T, ?, R> teeing(
        Collector<? super T, A1, R1> downstream1,
        Collector<? super T, A2, R2> downstream2,
        BiFunction<? super R1, ? super R2, R> merger) {

    class Acc {
        A1 acc1 = downstream1.supplier().get();
        A2 acc2 = downstream2.supplier().get();

        void accumulate(T t) {
            downstream1.accumulator().accept(acc1, t);
            downstream2.accumulator().accept(acc2, t);
        }

        Acc combine(Acc other) {
            acc1 = downstream1.combiner().apply(acc1, other.acc1);
            acc2 = downstream2.combiner().apply(acc2, other.acc2);
            return this;
        }

        R applyMerger() {
            R1 r1 = downstream1.finisher().apply(acc1);
            R2 r2 = downstream2.finisher().apply(acc2);
            return merger.apply(r1, r2);
        }
    }

    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::accumulate, Acc::combine, Acc::applyMerger);
}
```

Note: The characteristics of the downstream collectors are not considered when creating the returned collector (left as an exercise).

---

**EDIT 2:** Your solution is absolutely OK, even though it uses two streams. My solution above streams the original map only once, but it applies `func1` to all the values twice. If `func1` is expensive, you might consider *memoizing* it (i.e. caching its results, so that whenever it's called again with the same input, you return the result from the cache instead of computing it again). Or you might also first apply `func1` to the values of the original map, and then collect with `Collectors.teeing`.

Memoizing is easy. Just declare this utility method:

```
public <T, R> Function<T, R> memoize(Function<T, R> f) {
    Map<T, R> cache = new HashMap<>(); // or ConcurrentHashMap
    return k -> cache.computeIfAbsent(k, f);
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> func1 = memoize(x -> x); //This could be anything
```

Now you can use this memoized `func1` and it will work exactly as before, except that it will return results from the cache when its `apply` method is invoked with an argument that has been previously used.

The other solution would be to apply `func1` first and then collect:

```
Map.Entry<Map<Integer, BigDecimal>, List<BigDecimal>> result = data.entrySet().stream()
    .map(i -> Map.entry(i.getKey(), func1.apply(i.getValue())))
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
             Collectors.toMap(
                     Map.Entry::getKey, 
                     Map.Entry::getValue),
             Collectors.mapping(
                     i -> func2.apply(i.getValue()),
                     Collectors.toList()),
             Map::entry));
```

Again, I'm using jdk9's `Map.entry(K k, V v)` static method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the update. Just couldn't compare the complexity brought in here as compared to [the other solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53098210/1746118) ... maybe the question is interpreted incorrectly there?

Comment: @nullpointer The things is that OP wants *both* a new map with only `func1` applied to the values and also a list with `func2 ∘ func1` applied to them.

Comment: Hmm, now I get the choice of merge function and the return type of your solution. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified this way:

```
    List<BigDecimal> list = data.values().stream()
            .map(func1)
            .map(func2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to apply these functions to all the `BigDecimal` values in the `Map`. You can get all these values from the map using `Map::values` which returns the `List`. Then apply the Stream to the List only. Consider the `data` already contains some entries:

```
List<BigDecimal> list = data.values().stream()
                                     .map(func1)
                                     .map(func2)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I discourage you from iterating all the entries (`Set<Entry<Integer, BigDecimal>>`) since you only need to work with the values.

Comment: Together with list I need for the future the map updated with func1 only.

Comment: Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53098210/1746118) and not what the OP is looking for. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101844/1746118) for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @giuseppemaugeri: Could you describe the problem in the question better? I am not sure I understood it well.

Comment: @nullpointer: Seems we understood the question in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it returns Array of Object[2] the first one is the map and second one is the list

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> data = new HashMap<>();

        data.put(1, BigDecimal.valueOf(30));
        data.put(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(40));
        data.put(3, BigDecimal.valueOf(50));

        Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> func1 = x -> x.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));//This could be anything
        Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> func2 = y -> y.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(-20));//This could be anything


        Object[] o = data.entrySet().stream()
                .map(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::new)
                .map(entry -> {
                    entry.setValue(func1.apply(entry.getValue()));
                    return entry;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue), a -> {
                    List<BigDecimal> bigDecimals = a.values().stream().map(func2).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    return new Object[]{a,bigDecimals};
                }));
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println((Map<Integer, BigDecimal>)o[0]);
        System.out.println((List<BigDecimal>)o[1]);
```

Output:

```
 Original Map: {1=30, 2=40, 3=50}
 func1 map: {1=40, 2=50, 3=60}
 func1+func2 list: [20, 30, 40]
```